# API calls on a trigger is a best practice?

Tags: trigger, rest-api

I'm a bit wary on creating API calls on trigger. But with our process this is the only way we can achieve our requirements.

We have currently have almost 4 million limit on a 24-hour API calls and we use 400,000 calls, so I think there will be no problem if we process almost 50k records a day.

However, also read that we have a limit on future methods invocations. Our is less than 250,000. This is now I'm a bit confused. Our future method will only process one record.

Does anyone here who does create an api call on a trigger and later have problems?

And also is there any way we can achieve a real time sync to a third party app?

Thank you.

Comment: Read [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration) and [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) - these answer your questions on what's recommended/possible.

Comment: I would rather suggest to have these API calls in Batch process if you need to update certain information from other system in your Org record and requirement is not real time. You can consider batch processes for API call, trigger is of course not a preferred place but again it all depends upon the use case. Just be mindful of fact that you can have 100 (HTTP request ) calls in a single transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is NEVER code the logic in the Trigger. One company I used to be in had MULTIPLE active trigger logics in each object which was implemented before I got hired. The nightmare of having to clean up those multiple trigger logics into just one trigger wasted so much time when it could have been corrected in the beginning.

Anyway, there should only be ONE trigger per object and it should always look something like this. Feel free to add on after update, etc if needed.

```
trigger ObjectTrigger on <Object< (before insert,before update){
    switch on Trigger.OperationType{
        when BEFORE_INSERT {
            ObjectTriggerHandler_Service.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
        }
        when BEFORE_UPDATE {
            ObjectTriggerHandler_Service.onBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new ,Trigger.old,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

which should then flow to the general handler :

> ObjectTriggerHandler_Service

Inside this general handler, you then can create multiple specific handlers i.e. handler that calls the API callout class which you need.

Then since you were talking about "process almost 50k records a day". In that specific handler, you need to create a Future/Queueable (preferably Queueable as you can chain job together which Future cannot) class that implements Database.AllowsCallouts. An optionally a Scheduled Apex if you want to start at a certain time daily.

You also don't need to worry about the API call limit as I've personally handled more than 50k records a day and never ever once close to hitting the limit.

"Our future method will only process one record." You know you can batch up to 100 records for callouts?

Comment: +1 N.B. There are other "trigger handler:" patterns out there - e.g. [fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, you may be best served by delegating your API calls to an async transaction manager. This pattern can be seen in [Advanced Apex, Chapter 7 Going Asynchronous](https://advancedapex.com/advanced-apex-programming4/table-of-contents/) by Dan Appleman

The general notion is to use an SObject (`Async_Request__c`) as the signal to do something async.

- The Async Manager (which executes upon insertion into `Async_Request__c`) then delegates the work to queueable async handler classes which do the callout(s).
- If the handler succeeds, the Async_Request__c is marked as completed-success.
- If the async handler fails (e.g. the callout fails), the Async_Request__c is marked as Completed-Failed.
- Upon delegation, the Async Manager looks for the next Async_Request__c to work on

The huge advantage of this pattern is that it implicitly enables replay of failed API calls; one simply toggles the failed Async Requests back to their unplayed state and the Async Request Manager picks them up again

There are other variations of this pattern you can find by searching